# Receive only one message and then disconnect (Telethon)

Tags: python, telethon

I can't receive only one message because the NewMessage event continues firing after each message. But i need to receive only one message. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)

def check(event):
return (event.message.reply_markup is not None)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=(click_bot_id), incoming=True, func=lambda e: check(e)))
async def channelMessageHandler(event):
    channel_url = event.message.reply_markup.rows[0].buttons[0].url
    print(channel_url)

    print("Joining channel...")
    await client(JoinChannelRequest(channel_url))
    await event.message.click(0, 1)
    await client.disconnect()

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Calling `disconnect()` after a message arrives should definitely enough. Maybe you can enable `sequential_updates=True` in the constructor?

Comment: There is a problem with disconnect(). If another message arrives, when the first message is still processing, client will disconnect() after the second message is processed.

Comment: `client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash, sequential_updates=True)` Doesn't seem to help

Comment: the issue is when i have at least one 'await' statement i have problems with disconnecting after first message

Comment: it still manages to receieve and process second message

Comment: i've updated the code in question. This code definetly has this issue

Comment: @Lonami, can i somehow prevent the event from firing again after first message?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The thing happened because i processed the url inside event handler. So I moved code to a separate async method. And it worked. Big thanks to @Lonami though.

```
async def join_channel(channel_url):
print("- Joining channel " + channel_url + "...")
await client(JoinChannelRequest(channel_url))

def check(event):
    return (event.message.reply_markup is not None)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=(click_bot_id), incoming=True, func=lambda e: check(e)))
async def channelMessageHandler(event):
    global channel_url
    global message
    message = event.message
    channel_url = event.message.reply_markup.rows[0].buttons[0].url
    await client.disconnect()        

client.start()
client.loop.run_until_complete(send_join())
client.run_until_disconnected()
client.start()
client.loop.run_until_complete(join_channel(channel_url))
```